# Spring Security Auto Login not Persisted in HttpSession

Tags: spring-security

The below code creates a Spring Authentication object that has the role_user associated as when I looked at the SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext(); at the very end it does have the ROLE_USER and a principal of UserDetails so somehow its not getting associated to my HttpSession.  Any ideas?  My exception is below as well

```
public String login(){

    if(signUpDetailBean.getEmail() != null){

        sers currentUser = userManager.getUser(signUpDetailBean.getEmail());
        authenticateUserAndSetSession(currentUser, (HttpServletRequest) FacesUtils.getExternalContext().getRequest());
        clearForm();
        return "/registered/home.html";
    }else{
        clearForm();
        return "/auth/login.html";
    }

}

private void authenticateUserAndSetSession(Users user, HttpServletRequest request)
{
     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
     user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());

     // generate session if one doesn't exist
     request.getSession();

     token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
     Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
     SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
}
```

---

```
19:11:07,599 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/registered/home.html'; against '/javax.faces.resource/**'
19:11:07,600 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/registered/home.html'; against '/services/rest-api/1.0/**'
19:11:07,600 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/registered/home.html'; against '/preregistered/*'
19:11:07,600 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3486a602'
19:11:07,600 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:138 - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
19:11:07,600 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:84 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1985b723. A new one will be created.
19:11:07,601 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5b4c1313'
19:11:07,601 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5f787338'
19:11:07,601 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5cd4927f'
19:11:07,601 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:316 - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
19:11:07,602 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:316 - queryString: both null (property equals)
19:11:07,602 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:338 - requestURI: arg1=/dreamcatcher/registered/modify.html; arg2=/dreamcatcher/registered/home.html (property not equals)
19:11:07,602 DEBUG HttpSessionRequestCache:75 - saved request doesn't match
19:11:07,603 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7ddff76'
19:11:07,603 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@8afbefd'
19:11:07,603 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@775a9fdf'
19:11:07,604 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:68 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@d45457b8: Principal: guest; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de60: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 2A7602A6013D6200B7A663CEED58C478; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
19:11:07,604 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@51d394ab'
19:11:07,605 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@19c59085'
19:11:07,605 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /registered/home.html at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3c92218c'
19:11:07,605 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/registered/home.html'; against '/**/*.xhtml'
19:11:07,606 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/registered/home.html'; against '/auth/**'
19:11:07,606 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/registered/home.html'; against '/auth/*'
19:11:07,607 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/registered/home.html'; against '/registered/*'
19:11:07,607 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:191 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /registered/home.html; Attributes: [ROLE_USER]
19:11:07,608 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:291 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@d45457b8: Principal: guest; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de60: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 2A7602A6013D6200B7A663CEED58C478; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
19:11:07,608 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:53 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@44548719, returned: -1
19:11:07,616 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:53 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@554ff490, returned: 0
19:11:07,636 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:151 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
19:11:07,637 DEBUG HttpSessionRequestCache:41 - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/dreamcatcher/registered/home.html]
19:11:07,638 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:175 - Calling Authentication entry point.
19:11:07,638 DEBUG DefaultRedirectStrategy:36 - Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/dreamcatcher/auth/login.html'
19:11:07,639 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:90 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
19:11:07,651 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/auth/login.html'; against '/javax.faces.resource/**'
19:11:07,652 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/auth/login.html'; against '/services/rest-api/1.0/**'
19:11:07,652 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/auth/login.html'; against '/preregistered/*'
19:11:07,652 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3486a602'
19:11:07,653 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:138 - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
19:11:07,653 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:84 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1985b723. A new one will be created.
19:11:07,653 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5b4c1313'
19:11:07,653 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5f787338'
19:11:07,654 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5cd4927f'
19:11:07,654 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:316 - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
19:11:07,654 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:316 - queryString: both null (property equals)
19:11:07,655 DEBUG DefaultSavedRequest:338 - requestURI: arg1=/dreamcatcher/registered/home.html; arg2=/dreamcatcher/auth/login.html (property not equals)
19:11:07,655 DEBUG HttpSessionRequestCache:75 - saved request doesn't match
19:11:07,655 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7ddff76'
19:11:07,655 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@8afbefd'
19:11:07,656 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@775a9fdf'
19:11:07,656 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:68 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@d45457b8: Principal: guest; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de60: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 2A7602A6013D6200B7A663CEED58C478; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
19:11:07,656 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@51d394ab'
19:11:07,657 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@19c59085'
19:11:07,657 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:263 - /auth/login.html at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3c92218c'
19:11:07,658 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/auth/login.html'; against '/**/*.xhtml'
19:11:07,658 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:72 - Checking match of request : '/auth/login.html'; against '/auth/**'
19:11:07,658 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:191 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /auth/login.html; Attributes: [ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER]
19:11:07,659 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:291 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@d45457b8: Principal: guest; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de60: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 2A7602A6013D6200B7A663CEED58C478; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
19:11:07,659 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:53 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@44548719, returned: 1
19:11:07,659 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:212 - Authorization successful
19:11:07,660 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:222 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
19:11:07,660 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:252 - /auth/login.html reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
19:11:07,672 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:430 - Creating instance of bean 'authentication'
19:11:07,677 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'authentication': AutowiredFieldElement for com.dc.web.beans.LayoutBean com.dc.web.actions.BaseAction.layoutBean
19:11:07,678 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'authentication': AutowiredFieldElement for com.dc.web.beans.AuthenticationBean com.dc.web.actions.Authentication.authenticationBean
19:11:07,679 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'authentication': AutowiredFieldElement for com.dc.api.service.UserManager com.dc.web.actions.Authentication.userManager
19:11:07,679 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:242 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userManager'
19:11:07,680 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'authentication': AutowiredFieldElement for com.dc.api.service.Utilities com.dc.web.actions.Authentication.utilities
19:11:07,681 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:242 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'utilities'
19:11:07,681 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'authentication': AutowiredFieldElement for com.dc.web.util.PasswordMailContentHelper com.dc.web.actions.Authentication.passwordMailContentHelper
19:11:07,682 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:242 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'passwordMailContentHelper'
19:11:07,683 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'authentication': AutowiredFieldElement for com.dc.web.util.UsernameMailContentHelper com.dc.web.actions.Authentication.usernameMailContentHelper
19:11:07,683 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:242 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'usernameMailContentHelper'
19:11:07,684 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'authentication': AutowiredFieldElement for org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder com.dc.web.actions.Authentication.passwordEncoder
19:11:07,684 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:242 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'passwordEncoder'
19:11:07,685 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'authentication'
19:11:07,690 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:430 - Creating instance of bean 'signUpDetail'
19:11:07,692 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'signUpDetail': AutowiredFieldElement for com.dc.web.beans.LayoutBean com.dc.web.actions.BaseAction.layoutBean
19:11:07,692 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'signUpDetail': AutowiredFieldElement for private com.dc.web.beans.SignUpDetailBean com.dc.web.actions.SignUpDetail.signUpDetailBean
19:11:07,693 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'signUpDetail': AutowiredFieldElement for private com.dc.api.service.UserManager com.dc.web.actions.SignUpDetail.userManager
19:11:07,694 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:242 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userManager'
19:11:07,695 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'signUpDetail': AutowiredFieldElement for protected org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.dc.web.actions.SignUpDetail.authenticationManager
19:11:07,695 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:242 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
19:11:07,696 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'signUpDetail': AutowiredFieldElement for com.dc.api.service.Utilities com.dc.web.actions.SignUpDetail.utilities
19:11:07,697 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:242 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'utilities'
19:11:07,697 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'signUpDetail'
19:11:07,716 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:430 - Creating instance of bean 'layout'
19:11:07,717 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'layout': AutowiredFieldElement for com.dc.web.beans.LayoutBean com.dc.web.actions.BaseAction.layoutBean
19:11:07,718 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:82 - Processing injected method of bean 'layout': AutowiredFieldElement for private com.dc.web.beans.LayoutBean com.dc.web.actions.Layout.layoutBean
19:11:07,719 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'layout'
19:11:07,738 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:98 - Chain processed normally
19:11:07,738 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:271 - SecurityContext contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
19:11:07,739 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:90 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: can you try redirect like this: return "redirect:CONTEXT-PATH/registered/home.html"; Replace CONTEXT-PATH by your context.

Comment: @Ritesh I tried a redirect as well and I get the same issue.  I added my entire log from the point where the redirect occurs.  I have Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); right before the redirect and the user role is there and the principal object is correct. It seems like its not keeping the object in session after the redirect or post....any ideas?

Comment: Ritesh, I've also tried to create a RememberMeAuthenticationToken insteaad of a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken as I'm using <remember-me user-service-ref="userManager" key="keyvalue"/> but I get an No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken when I do that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to put the security context in session. Otherwise it won't work. You can use this

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

request.getSession().setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

Comment: where do you add those lines?

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: Please explain where to add. Please post a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

To build onto manishpal's answer, I'll give some context on where to put it. (I am using Kotlin, sorry for the different syntax)

Within your application, you will probably have some kind of function that handles authentication of a user. Within my application, it is a POST endpoint for login.

```kotlin
@PostMapping("/login")
fun handleLogin(@RequestParam username:String?, @RequestParam password:String?) {
  authenticate(username, password)
  return "redirect:/"
}

fun authenticate(username:String?, password:String?) {
  val user = database.findByUserName(username)
  if(user.password != password) throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

Now, this is where I would add the first line of pal's answer. Spring applications have a static object called the `SecurityContextHolder` which you can use to access the details of the currently logged in user. In this case, we are going to set the authentication of this context ourselves.

```kotlin
fun authenticate(username:String?, password:String?) {
  val user = database.findByUserName(username)
  if (user.password != password) throw IllegalArgumentException()
  val token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.username, user.password)
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = token
}
```

Now, we have set the authentication of the user in the context of this request, but it will go away after this endpoint finishes executing. We now want to set the authentication for the user across the entire session that the user is active. For this, we will have to add another parameter to our login endpoint:

```kotlin
@PostMapping("/login")
fun handleLogin(@RequestParam username:String?, @RequestParam password:String?, request: HttpServletRequest) {
  authenticate(username, password)
  request.session.setAttribute(
    HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
  )
  return "redirect:/"
}
```

This `request` parameter is automatically wired into the function call by spring, so no action is needed to include it in your HTTP request to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm losing my login credentials between a successful login and the redirect from my AuthenticationSuccessHandler in one app, but not in another that's essentially doing the same things.