# Spring Boot 3 Redis Indexed Session - Failure to save login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I am upgrading my team's Spring Boot project from 2.7.5 to 3.0.0, which includes a migration of the now deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. I am working in Kotlin, but I do not believe the language impacts the performance of the component.

In both the old and new versions of the security configuration class, I have declared this `Autowired` field and corresponding bean:

```kotlin
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var sessionRepository: FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<out Session>

    @Bean
    fun sessionRegistry(): SessionRegistry {
        return SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(sessionRepository)
    }
```

At first, my application would not start, because Spring could not wire the session repository into my configuration, but after some digging, it was because I had to change the `@EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation to

```kotlin
@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession
class SecurityConfiguration(
```

---

Now, my current issue with the application is that I cannot log into my application, and I think it has to do with the Redis session management.

I am able to load the login page, and submit a login request. When I submit the request, I am able to see all of the normal debug messages my application prints associated with logging in, taking me through a successful authentication. When all of that finishes, my application redirects the user to the main page, which checks if a user's `authentication != null`, and redirects them to the main page if so. However, the authentication at this point is null, and there is not an entry in redis for this user's authentication.

In case it helps, this is what the security configuration had defined in the `SecurityFilterChain` bean for the session parts before the migration:

```kotlin
.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession().and()
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).expiredUrl("/api/v1/logout").and()
```

and after:

```kotlin
.sessionManagement { ssm ->
  ssm.sessionFixation { it.migrateSession() }
  ssm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
    .maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).expiredUrl("/api/v1/logout")
}
```

Is there something I am missing to allow the user authentication to persist? I have not touched any part of the code for this migration besides the pom.xml file and the rewriting of the security configuration.

---

UPDATE: I have altered the tags of the security configuration, in a desperate attempt at getting something to save.

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableSpringHttpSession
@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession(redisNamespace = "admindev:session", flushMode = FlushMode.IMMEDIATE, saveMode = SaveMode.ALWAYS)
class SecurityConfiguration(
```

I have increased the logging level for spring security, and everything looks fine, until the session token is not found.

---

Update 2:

I have tweaked my application as I have described in [my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74803772/13189015), and I am now able to access the frontend of my application. However, when I attempt to login through the backend, I get caught up in an infinite redirection loop. The app tries to send me to the error/4xx page, which is the correct behavior, since we don't have a "/" link on the backend, but then the app tries to redirect me according to the "your session has expired" page, and since I'm logged in, it tries to redirect me back to "/"...

Looking through the logs, it seems to be related to the exception handling I set up on my filter chain:

```kotlin
http.exceptionHandling { e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(LoginRedirectHandler()) }
//...
class LoginRedirectHandler : LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login") {
    override fun determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        exception: AuthenticationException?
    ): String {
        return "${this.loginFormUrl}?error=timeout&requestedUrl=${request.requestURL}"
    }
}
```

Now, the question becomes: the backend webpages were not looping before, what could have changed about this behavior?